# Proof using Bolzano's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Im having relatively hard time with this particular problem. We're asked to prove this:

Show, that there exists a real number $x$, which satisfies $x^5 − x^2 + 3 = 2019$

The thing is that we should use Bolzano's theorem for this and construct a reasonably rigorous proof, but wouldn't this work also with Intermediate value theorem? How should one approach this?

Comment: Any odd degree polynomial has atleast one real root.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned correctly in the comments,every odd degree polynomial has a real root.

As another simple proof take $h(x)=x^5-x^2-2016$ and apply Bolzano's theorem to the interval $[0,10]$

Comment: Could you elaborate, how do we come up with the interval $[0, 10]$?

Comment: @Daniel you just find an interval where $h(x)<0$ in one endpoint and $h(x)>0$  in the other

Comment: Im bit stuck... how do i find the interval?

Comment: @Daniel ...there is not a explicit way...just try numbers  to achive what i said in my above comment.